# Android - How to handle when the link is clicked on TextView via Linkify

Tags: android, textview, linkify

I wanna do something additional act when the link is clicked on TextView.

The link on TextView is made via xml setting or using Linkify class. Like `android:autoLink="true"` or `Linkify(textView, Linkify.WEB_URLS);`

How do I catch the event when the link is click?

Comment: use this android:autoLink="true"

Comment: @shinisuba I know, I know. I already wrote on the question. My question is how can I catch the event. I wanna add additional function when the link is clicked.

Comment: Do you want entire text content to be clickable?

Comment: @ManishMulimani, I want to set a statement(like `isClicked = true`) when the user click the link and web browser is executed. @Manish

Answer (score 0):

Rather than the Linkify library, use this code:

```
final boolean[] isClicked = {false};
final AppCompatActivity activity = getActivity();//or use 'this' if already in an activity 
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        isClicked[0] = true;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(textView.getText().toString()));
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Note that I've replaced your original `boolean isClicked` with `boolean[] isClicked`. This is because you can only use final variables in inner classes, and once `isClicked` is finalized you can't reassign it.